# how to return response from post in a variable? jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, return-value

**edited:**
This is what i need:

```
sendpost = function(a,b,c){
    return jQuery.post('inc/operations.php', {a:b}, c, "json");
},

rotate = function(callback){
    //....
    alert(callback);
}

sendpost('operation', 'test', rotate)
```

**old post:**
i use this function to return the response of post:

```
$.sendpost = function(){
    return jQuery.post('inc/operations.php', {'operation':'test'}, "json");
},
```

i want to make something like this:

in:

```
$.another = function(){
  var sendpost = $.sendpost();
  alert(sendpost);
}
```

but i get: `[object XMLHttpRequest]`

if i print the object with:

```
jQuery.each(sendpost, function(i, val) {
  $(".displaydetails").append(i + " => " + val + "<br/>");
});
```

i get:

```
details  abort => function () { x && h.call(x); g("abort"); }
dispatchEvent => function dispatchEvent() { [native code] }
removeEventListener => function removeEventListener() { [native code] }
open => function open() { [native code] }
setRequestHeader => function setRequestHeader() { [native code] }
onreadystatechange => [xpconnect wrapped nsIDOMEventListener]
send => function send() { [native code] }
readyState => 4
status => 200
getResponseHeader => function getResponseHeader() { [native code] }
responseText => mdaaa from php
```

how to return only the response in the variable?

Comment: Why on earth are you putting all of your functions inside `$`?

Comment: if not i get: $.functionname  is not a function

Comment: *cries*. $ is the jQuery object. If you define functions normally (`function bar () { alert('Foo'); }`), you do NOT call the function using `$.bar()`, it's simply `bar()`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.

AJAX calls are asynchronous, meaning that your code continues running before the server sends a reply.

When the `return` statement executes, there is no reply from the server yet.

It is possible to make a synchronous AJAX call, but it will completely freeze the browser and should be avoided at all costs.

Instead, you should make your function take a callback that will receive the server's response, and call that callback from `$.post`'s callback.  (This is how jQuery's AJAX functions return values)

**EDIT**: For example:

```
$.sendpost = function(callback) {
    return jQuery.post('inc/operations.php', {'operation':'test'}, callback, "json");
};

$.another = function() { 
    $.sendpost(function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
};
```

Comment: how i can make a callback to recive the server's response?
can u post a little example? thanks!

Comment: i receive this error in firebug: 'e.success.call is not a function'

Comment: The callback parameter is the name of a function to be executed after the post function completes? i can put a name of a function there?

Comment: You can pass an anonymous function, like I did, or the name of a regular function.  (Without `()`, as that would _call_ the function)

Comment: i made a function:     $.myalert = function(callback){
        alert(callback);
    }
and i put myalert , $.myalert, $.myalert() @ the end of the post, but nopw, not working :(

Comment: Change it to $.myAlert.  Or, stop putting your functions inside $.

Comment: i still get: e.success.call is not a function
e.success.call(k,o,i,x);e.global&&f("a...test(e.url)||(e.url+=(ka.test(e.url)?

Comment: Pass the callback before the `"json"` argument, as in my edited example.

Comment: :(( is not calling alert() function skips, but do the post call

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsbin.com/okade3/edit).  What version of jQuery are you using?